# Benchmark for main thread and other thread in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, benchmarking, stopwatch

I'm given a problem to demonstrate a benchmark for executing functions using Single and Multithread.
Am I doing right here? If yes, how can I do so without using Join().
If no, suggest me.

**Code**

```
class Threading1 
{
  static void Main (string[] args) 
  {
     Stopwatch timerMain, timerThreads;

     // Main thread 
     timerMain = Stopwatch.StartNew ();
     func1();
     func2();
     func3();
     timerMain.Stop ();
     Console.WriteLine ("Time taken for Main thread: " + timerMain.ElapsedMilliseconds);

     // Other threads
     Thread t1 = new Thread (() => Threading1.func1 ());
     Thread t2 = new Thread (() => Threading1.func2 ());
     Thread t3 = new Thread (() => Threading1.func3 ());
     timerThreads = Stopwatch.StartNew ();
     t1.Start(); t1.Join();
     t2.Start(); t2.Join();
     t3.Start(); t3.Join();
     timerThreads.Stop ();
     Console.WriteLine ("Time taken for Other threads: " + timerThreads.ElapsedMilliseconds);
  }

  // Find maximum value in an array
  static void func1() 
  {
    // Code here. 
  }

  // Find minimum value in an array
  static void func2()
  {
    // Code here. 
  }

  // Find average value of an array
  static void func3()
  {
    // Code here. 
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
Time taken for Main thread: 44
Time taken for other threads: 10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I advice you to use [Tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235608.aspx) and method [WaitAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd270695.aspx) to wait, when all tasks are completed.

```
timerThreads = Stopwatch.StartNew();
var t1 = Task.Run(() => Threading1.func1());
var t2 = Task.Run(() => Threading1.func2());
var t3 = Task.Run(() => Threading1.func3());

Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3);
timerThreads.Stop ();
Console.WriteLine ("Time taken for Other threads: " + timerThreads.ElapsedMilliseconds);
```

In your solution there is no parallel working, all threads are execition one by one.

Comment: I would not recommend using `Task.Factory.StartNew` and instead use `Task.Run`, it is very easy to accidentally get stuff to run on the UI thread instead of the thread pool when you use `StartNew` without passing in a scheduler, `Task.Run` always uses the thread pool scheduler.

Comment: It works like charm. :) But I wonder why my code is not working in parallel. Isn't threading for achieving parallelism.?

Comment: Thanks for your immediate responses. You saved my day. :) 
Can't I achieve the result using Thread itself?

Comment: @NaveenKumarV Your code does not run in parallel because you wait for each thread **as soon as you start it**. If you insist on using `Thread` instead of `Task`, try this: `t1.Start(); t2.Start(); t3.Start(); t1.Join();t2.Join();t3.Join();`